# is there anyway in windows to find recently changed files in a folder but exclude a sub folder

Tags: windows-xp, windows-search

i have a folder:

```
C:\myfolder
```

and i want to find all files in this folder (and subfolders) that have changed in the past week.  i also want to ignore the folder:

```
C:\myfolder\test\test21
```

in this search

is there anyway in windows xp to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a search by modification by opening the folder and clicking on search then all files and folders. There will be an option asking when it was modified you can pick within the last week or you can specify what dates. Unfornunately you can not ignore a specific subfolder when doing this search. My recommendation would be to move that subfolder temporarily and then placing it back after the search has been completed.